# How to make function run forever in the browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

I have a simple function that fetches some data, shows it to the user (on a chart), wait for 10 minutes and starts again. After some time I get this error
`Error: timeout of 0ms exceeded`

I found this supposed to happen if it can't connect to the internet, which cannot be the case.

Is chrome doing this maybe? I think it might freeze the app or something.

Here is the simple function:

```
    updateReports() {
      // checks for new data, waits the given time, and checks again.. forever
      this.$VKS.Read('Report', { filter: { shared: this.user }})
      .then(reports => {
        this.reports = reports // show the data to the user
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.updateReports() // start again
        }, 1000 * 60 * 10) // 10 minutes
      }).catch(err => console.error(err))
    },
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

if you get error(in this case `Timeout`) your codes never retry. you need to do the same in catch statement:

```
 updateReports() {
  // checks for new data, waits the given time, and checks again.. forever
  this.$VKS.Read('Report', { filter: { shared: this.user }})
  .then(reports => {
    this.reports = reports // show the data to the user
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.updateReports() // start again
    }, 1000 * 60 * 10) // 10 minutes
  }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      setTimeout(() => {
       this.updateReports() // start again
      }, 1000 * 60 * 10) // 10 minutes
  })
},
```

Comment: Alright, i'll add that and see if there is any difference

Comment: doesn't it retry after error in 10 mins?